# Error second time I run a migration. It appears the Generic Repo needs to be disposed, I have no idea how

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, blazor, unit-of-work

Please bear with me I am really struggling here.

I am relatively new to EF Core with dependency injection. I come from the old asp.net world of newing classes etc but want to try and use dependency injection. Since our old database also needs to be migrated to the new structure I thought a good first app would be to write an app that will use the dependency injection. I decided to use Blazor as our final codebase.

There are two databases one Called QOnT and one called iSele. I am migrating the data from QOnT to iSele - using a number of websites including https://ngohungphuc.wordpress.com/2018/05/01/generic-repository-pattern-in-asp-net-core/ and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application - I created two generic repositories. One for use with the QOnT tables and one that will be the final app repo. I also created a generic Unit of Work for both.

The Generics are more or less the same as on Tony's Tech & Language Blog or  https://ngohungphuc.wordpress.com/ Except for one change that caters for the fact that I need to insert and update items that are in identity fields. so I have created a generic routine that disables identity-checking then does the insert and turns it back on. I have pasted it below:

```
public T AddWithIDOn(T entity, string TableName)
    {
        _loggerManager.LogDebug($"FancyRepo -> AddWithIDOn {typeof(T)}, enttity {entity.ToString()}, Table: {TableName} ");
        _context.Database.OpenConnection();
        try
        {
            _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw($"SET IDENTITY_INSERT {TableName} ON");
            _context.Set<T>().Add(entity);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw($"SET IDENTITY_INSERT {TableName} OFF");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _loggerManager.LogInfo($"!!!Error!!! FancyRepo -> AddWithIDOn error: {ex.Message}");
        }
        finally
        {
            _context.Database.CloseConnection();
        }
        return entity;
    }
```

This works fine.

In the Startup.cs I add the DbContexts and the unit of works

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddServerSideBlazor();
        services.AddDbContextPool<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("iSeleConnection"));
            options.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking);
            options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging(true);
        });
        services.AddDbContext<QOnTDbContext>(qontoptions =>
        {
            qontoptions.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("QOnTConnection"));
        });

        //services.AddScoped(typeof(IQOnTGenericRepository<>), typeof(QOnTGenericRepository<>));
        services.AddScoped(typeof(IQOnTUnitOfWork), typeof(QOnTUnitOfWork));

        // services.AddScoped(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), typeof(IGenericRepository<>));
        services.AddScoped(typeof(IUnitOfWork), typeof(UnitOfWork));

        // logger
        services.AddSingleton<ILoggerManager, LoggerManager>();
    }
```

You will see I have commented out the services.addscoped for the repost is the Unitofwork creates them.

then I have a "code-behind" or whatever it is called behind my razor for Migrate customer that is a CompnentBase

So

```
  public partial class MigrateCustomersBase : ComponentBase
```

In there I inject the two UnitOfWorks

```
[Inject]
private IQOnTUnitOfWork _QOnTUnitOfWork { get; set; }
[Inject]
private IUnitOfWork _iSeleUnitOfWork { get; set; }
```

I have a button on the form that is clicked to do the migration:

```
            IQOnTGenericRepository<CustomerTypeTbl> QOnTCustomerTypeTbl = _QOnTUnitOfWork.Repository<CustomerTypeTbl>();

            ICollection<CustomerTypeTbl> QOnTCustomerTypes = QOnTCustomerTypeTbl.GetAll();

            foreach (var srcCusType in QOnTCustomerTypes)
            {

                CustomerType tgtCusType = _iSeleUnitOfWork.Repository<CustomerType>().Find(ct => ct.CustomerTypeID == srcCusType.CustTypeId);

                if (tgtCusType == null)
                {
                    Logger.LogDebug($"  *Inserting CustomerType with id: {srcCusType.CustTypeId} and name {srcCusType.CustTypeDesc}");
                    _iSeleUnitOfWork.Repository<CustomerType>().AddWithIDOn(new CustomerType
                        {
                            CustomerTypeID = srcCusType.CustTypeId,
                            CustomerTypeName = srcCusType.CustTypeDesc,
                            HasExtendedOptions = false,
                            Notes= string.Format("Migrated from QOnT.CustomerTypeTbl {0:d}", DateTime.UtcNow.Date)                        
                        }
                        , "iSele.CustomerTypes");
                }
                else
                {
                    tgtCusType.CustomerTypeName = srcCusType.CustTypeDesc;
                    tgtCusType.HasExtendedOptions = false;
                    tgtCusType.Notes = string.Format("Migrated from QOnT.CustomerTypeTbl {0:d}", DateTime.UtcNow.Date);
                    Logger.LogDebug($"  *Updating Area with id: {tgtCusType.CustomerTypeID} and name {tgtCusType.CustomerTypeName}");
                    _iSeleUnitOfWork.Repository<CustomerType>().Update(tgtCusType);
                }

            }
        }
```

So after all this what is my issue. Well, the first time I run the code everything works fine. However, if I click the button again (call the code) then I get an error

*The instance of entity type 'CustomerType' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{CustomerTypeID: 1}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.*

To me, this looks like multiple UnitOfWorks exist. If I navigate away from the page and come back it works again. It is just the second time the button is clicked it does not work. What am I doing wrong, how do I dispose of the UnitOfWork- do I need to refresh the page or something?

Comment: either change unit of works lifetime to transient or disabled tracking in EF settings globally or per request by calling .AsNoTracking()

Comment: I have tried both infact in the code above you will see ''options.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking);

services.AddTransient(typeof(IUnitOfWork), typeof(UnitOfWork)); - same error

Comment: That is in the startup.cs

Comment: actually looks like you have items in the loop with the same primary key ids so it doesn't know how to differentiate them. maybe try with adding alternate key?

Comment: I cannot believe that is the issue. No mater what table I migrate I have that issu.e Why do I need an alternative key if it works perfectly the first time I run the migration both the update and the insert? If I go out and come back in everything works fine.How can that be a key issue?

Comment: I'm not sure. if tracking is off and you persist changes immediately after the loop then there shouldn't be this tracking conflict

Comment: Okay so I change the code to mot used dependency injection and everythign works. But this is a bit pointless. Everyone says you must use it.

See answer - since cannot post as comment'

Answer (score 0):

So I stopped using dependency injection I modified the function that is called on click as follows:

```
       var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(ConString);
        optionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging(true);
        optionsBuilder.EnableDetailedErrors(true);

        ApplicationDbContext _iSeleDbContext = new ApplicationDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
        UnitOfWork _iSeleUnitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(_iSeleDbContext, Logger);

        IQOnTFancyGenericRepository<CustomerTypeTbl> QOnTCustomerTypeTbl = _QOnTUnitOfWork.Repository<CustomerTypeTbl>();

        ICollection<CustomerTypeTbl> QOnTCustomerTypes = QOnTCustomerTypeTbl.GetAll();

        foreach (var srcCusType in QOnTCustomerTypes)
        {
            CustomerType tgtCusType = _iSeleUnitOfWork.Repository<CustomerType>().Find(ct => ct.CustomerTypeID == srcCusType.CustTypeId);

            if (tgtCusType == null)
            {
                //await 
                Logger.LogDebug($"  *Inserting CustomerType with id: {srcCusType.CustTypeId} and name {srcCusType.CustTypeDesc}");
                _iSeleUnitOfWork.Repository<CustomerType>().AddWithIDOn(new CustomerType
                {
                    CustomerTypeID = srcCusType.CustTypeId,
                    CustomerTypeName = srcCusType.CustTypeDesc,
                    HasExtendedOptions = false,
                    Notes = string.Format("Migrated from QOnT.CustomerTypeTbl {0:d}", DateTime.UtcNow.Date)
                }
                    , "iSele.CustomerTypes");
            }
            else
            {
                tgtCusType.CustomerTypeName = srcCusType.CustTypeDesc;
                tgtCusType.HasExtendedOptions = false;
                tgtCusType.Notes = string.Format("Migrated from QOnT.CustomerTypeTbl {0:d}", DateTime.UtcNow.Date);
                Logger.LogDebug($"  *Updating Area with id: {tgtCusType.CustomerTypeID} and name {tgtCusType.CustomerTypeName}");
                _iSeleUnitOfWork.Repository<CustomerType>().Update(tgtCusType);
            }
        }

        _iSeleUnitOfWork.Dispose();
```

So I am lost now. Dependency injection seems to suck. But why do people  all over the internet recommend it. This is not a practicle solution.

Comment: After running multiple test it seems this is linked to the fact that EF core does not like having the identity turn off. I have not been able to figure out a way to force the EF DbSet model to reset to fix this.